# Python output don't show in CMD

Tags: python, cmd

If I run this script in CMD (or Git Bash - doesn't matter) using `python name.py`, output will show only `hello` and not the return value. Why is that? I tried to reinstall python, add PATH, uninstall Anaconda and install only python from official website. Code is working fine in jupyter notebook.

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    return ' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in string.split())

to_jaden_case("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real")

print("hello")
```

Comment: Because Python intentionally doesn't show (return) values unless you explicitly print them. The solution is simple: call `print` and pass it the value you want to print.

Comment: Just like you have `print("hello")` to print hello, you should have `print(to_jaden_case("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"))` to print whatever the function returns.

Comment: When you call a function in the REPL, in interactive Python, it will print the result value of the previous expression for every line. But calling a function in a script will lose the value returned unless you assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the return value

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    return ' '.join(word.capitalize() for word in string.split())

print(to_jaden_case("How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"))

print("hello")
```